# How to Post data from postman to Output.json file?

Tags: node.js, rest, api

In the below code I am getting output like this without comma it's creating new array again I don't want like this I want like lastly I mentioned

Test.json

```
[
    {
        "name":"alpha",
        "password": "123"
    },
    {
        "name":"beta",
        "password": "321"
    }
]{
  "name":"Gokul",
  "pass":"098"
}
```

Main.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/myData', function (req, res) {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        fs.appendFile("test.json", data, 'utf8', function (err, file) {
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            console.log("The file was saved!");
            res.send("Received");

        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () { });
```

But i want output like this :

```
[
    {
        "name":"alpha",
        "password": "123"
    },
    {
        "name":"beta",
        "password": "321"
    },
    {
        "name":"gokul",
        "password": "098"
    }
]
```

Can anyone help me and edit my code to the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to `merge` the jsons together.

What you need to do is, in that order:

1. Read the full `test.json` file
2. Parse the content as json
3. Push the json the received into the array
4. Write it back as a json file (stringify it before)

Comment: I am new to node and json concept if possible can you edit my code sir

Comment: We're sadly no here to write code for you, but to help you learn. Try to research about how to do each step, and post a new question if there's a step you're blocked on, with what you tried.

Comment: How to push the json to array file

Answer (score 0):

STOP!! Don't reinvent the wheel, what you need is similar to a local JSON database like Lowdb. Why don't you take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb). Perfect for your use case.